# Use a recursion tree to determine a good asymptotic upper bound on the recurrence T(n) =T(n/2) +n^2.

Tags: asymptotics, recursion, upper-lower-bounds

I am quite confused on this one, found this while going through a book. The book also says that it can be verified using substitution. I have no idea how to approach this one since I am quite new to algorithms. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try first $n = 2^k$ and start with $k = 2, 3, 4,$ and see the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep substituting
and see what appears.

$\begin{array}\\
t(n)
&=t(n/2)+n^2\\
&=t(n/4)+(n/2)^2+n^2\\
&=t(n/4)+(1+1/2^2)n^2\\
&=t(n/8)+(n/4)^2+(1+1/2^2)n^2\\
&=t(n/8)+(1+1/2^2+1/4^2)n^2\\
&=t(n/16)+(n/8)^2+(1+1/2^2+1/4^2)n^2\\
&=t(n/16)+(1+1/2^2+1/4^2+1/8^2)n^2\\
\end{array}
$

It looks like

$\begin{array}\\
t(n)
&=t(n/2^k)+n^2\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}1/2^{2j}\\
&=t(n/2^k)+n^2\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}1/4^{j}\\
&=t(n/2^k)+n^2\dfrac{1-1/4^k}{1-1/4}\\
&=t(n/2^k)+n^2\dfrac{4(1-1/4^k)}{3}\\
&<t(n/2^k)+\dfrac43 n^2\\
\end{array}
$